# Understanding deconv in Matlab, how it works

Tags: matlab, convolution

I am trying to understand how `deconv` works in Matlab.

Can anyone clarify that for me by explaining how this is calculated

```
[quotient,remainder]=deconv([1 2 8 4 4],[1 1 2 2])

quotient=
1     1

remainder=
0     0     5     0     2
```

I need to understand the step by step method of calculation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you understand [polynomial (long) division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), you already have it. This result just says that

> x^4 + 2x^3 + 8x^2 + 4x + 4

divided by

> x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 2

equals

> x + 1

with remainder

> 5x^2 + 2

The reason is that [convolution is the same as polynomial multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution), and thus deconvolution is polynomial division.

This is mentioned in [`deconv` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/deconv.html):

> If u and v are vectors of polynomial coefficients, convolving them is equivalent to multiplying the two polynomials, and deconvolution is polynomial division. The result of dividing v by u is quotient q and remainder r.